# The menu is not displayed in mac os 10.9.1

Tags: macos, cocoa, menubar

In my application used "Application is agent(UIElement)" = YES.

I use it to hide the second process.
But first process need show.

For show process I used code:

```
// display dock icon
TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);

// enable menu bar
SetSystemUIMode(kUIModeNormal, 0);

// switch to Dock.app
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.dock"    options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault additionalEventParamDescriptor:nil launchIdentifier:nil];

// switch back
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:TRUE];
```

The problem is that the menu is not displayed. But if you switch to some other program and back, the menu appears.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the documentation? The class method [+[NSMenu setMenuBarVisible:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenu_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000267-BBCEEEHH) is exactly what you are looking for, found by searching the documentation for "menu visible".

Comment: I know this method, but it does not help. And I also know how to read.

Comment: At the moment I set the option "Application is agent (UIElement)" = NO.

When launching the second process calls [[NSApplication sharedApplication] setActivationPolicy:YES]. But in this case there is an icon in the panel process, and then disappears, which in my case is not correct. The user should not see that process is started.

Comment: First, it's not possible to guess at what you know of or have tried and since you didn't mention the obvious method (or use it in your code above), it's reasonable to expect the obvious to be pointed out to you. Second, your comment here is different from "How to show menubar..." and "The problem is that the menu is not displayed." Please edit and rewrite your question to be a LOT more specific with details and used code.